How to reject any form of buttons grouping or hide labels on the taskbar in Windows 11?
I go to the taskbar settings and disable the option to combine taskbar buttons and hide labels, but even so, notice that there is a gigantic empty space with nothing and all the buttons together:


well, yes if you have Taskbar alignment set to "left" it will behave this way unless you open so many windows that it fills that region..
